# Use a derived class type as parameter of a base method in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following classes in the following files:

```
    // Tensor.hh
    template <class T>
    class Tensor {
        /* declarations */
    }
```

---

```
    // Tensor.cpp
    #include "Tensor.hh"
    // Implementation of Tensor.hh
```

---

```
    // Kernel.hh
    #include "Tensor.hh"
    template <class T>
    class Kernel : public Tensor<T> {
       /* declarations */
    }
```

---

```
    // Kernel.cpp
    #include "Kernel.hh"
    // Implementation of Kernel.hh
```

---

Is it possible to use a pointer to "Kernel" as parameter of a "Tensor" method?
Something like:

```
    template <class T>
    void Tensor<T>::foo(Kernel<T>* kernel) {
        // Do something...
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Did you get an error when you tried?  Did you `#include "Kernel.hh"` in the file you tried to define the function in?

Comment: With the appropriate includes/forward declaration is possible. Whether this is a good idea, well.... probably isn't it's a cyclic dependecy between classes, which are better avoided.

Comment: The implementation of class/function templates has to be visible to the users of those templates. So you can't have separate cpp files for the implementation unless you expect your users to directly `#include` those cpp files.

Comment: Not sure if this will actually come up for you or not, but [standard link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) about potential pitfalls of splitting class template definitions into header and source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. In your `Tensor.cpp` you will have to include `#include "Kernel.hh"`, and in your `Tensor.hh` you will have to add a forward declaration:

```
template<typename>
class Kernel;
```

Usually I would really avoid forward declaring template classes, and I would avoid circular dependencies. Sometimes they are not avoidable, but sometimes yes.

Another solution would be to simply implement `foo` as a free function in another header:

```
void foo(Tensor<T>& tensor, Kernel<T>* kernel) {
    // ...
}
```

That way you break the circular dependency, and you get bonus encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use forward declaration of the class Kernel. I could compile following:

```cpp
 template <class T>
    class Kernel;


 template <class T>
    class Tensor {
        /* declarations */
     void foo(Kernel<T>* kernel);
    };

 template <class T>
    class Kernel: public Tensor<T> {
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of your class templates needs to be visible to your users. So it's best to put the implementation directly in the header file.

```
// Forward declare Kernel<T> so Tensor<T> can know about it for foo()
template<typename T>
class Kernel;

// Define Tensor<T>
template<typename T>
class Tensor {
    void foo(Kernel<T>* kernel);
    ...
};

// Define Kernel<T>
template<typename T>
class Kernel : public Tensor<T> {
    ...
};

// Define Tensor<T>::foo here since Kernel<T> needs to be defined
// for it to do anything meaningful with it
template<typename T>
void Tensor<T>::foo(Kernel<T> *kernel) {
    // Do something...
}
```